# shift content of a dictionary by specified size to a new dictionary in C# LInq

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a help in C#, LINQ to write a method that accepts a dictionary and integer (shifting size)
and returns another dictionary with all values shifted to right by the size specified.
here is the example.
the dictionary looks like this;

```
01/01/2015 --- 100
02/01/2015 --- 150
03/01/2015 --- 200
```

Code:

```
IDictionary<DateTime, int> inputDic = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
inputDic.Add(new DateTime(2015, 01, 01), 100);
inputDic.Add(new DateTime(2015, 02, 01), 150);
inputDic.Add(new DateTime(2015, 03, 01), 200);

public static IDictionary<DateTime, int> ShiftContent(
        this IDictionary<DateTime, int> inputDictionary, int size)
    {
        //shifting logic;
        return outputDictionary;

    }
```

So if the size is 2, the output dictionary should contain values as below; below dates are in mm/dd/yyyy.

```
01/01/2015 --- 0
02/01/2015 --- 0
03/01/2015 --- 100
04/01/2015 --- 150
05/01/2015 --- 200
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Shifted to the right", huh? Right shift is easy: `n >>= 2`. Give it a whirl. What did you try that didn't work? Are you asking somebody to help you fix a problem, or are you just lying there in tears begging somebody to write your code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another way only using only one linq query :

```
public static IDictionary<DateTime, int> ShiftContent(
        this IDictionary<DateTime, int> inputDictionary, int size)
{       
    return 
        Enumerable.Range(1, size).Select(value => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(inputDictionary.First().Key.AddMonths(value - 1), 0))     
        .Union(inputDictionary.ToList().Select(value => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(value.Key.AddMonths(size), value.Value)))
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would do the job:

```
public static IDictionary<DateTime, int> ShiftContent(
        this IDictionary<DateTime, int> inputDictionary, int size)
{
    var minDate = inputDictionary.Keys.Min();
    var result = inputDictionary.ToDictionary(a => a.Key.AddMonths(size), a => a.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result[minDate.AddMonths(i)] = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Powel. it worked. I made a slight change to the return statement to maintain the order.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very easy to create a foreach to do exactly what you want, but the below is a Linq solution.

What you need to do is:

- Create a list of the new dates that need to be added to your list.
- Concat that list to your original list.
- Query the combined list and do a simple condition to check if the element should be 0 or a shifted element.
- You may need to check if the dictionary have elements or not and you need to add more checks if there is a circular shift (shift >= count or multiple of count).

The below should pave your way to do it correctly:

```
var last = inputDic.Keys.LastOrDefault();
int skipped = inputDic.Count - shift;
var tobeAdded = inputDic.Skip(skipped).Select((item, index) => new 
                                              KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> 
                                              (last.AddMonths(index + 1),  
                                              inputDic.Values.ElementAt(skipped + index)));

int counter = 0;
var result = (from kv in inputDic.AsEnumerable().Concat(tobeAdded)
              let value = counter <= shift - 1 ? 0 : inputDic.Values.ElementAt(counter - shift)
              let dummy = counter++
              select Tuple.Create(kv.Key, value))
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear steps. this makes me clear on how to approach.